# Red Black Tree in C++, deletion algorithm

Tags: c++, red-black-tree

From "Introduction to alghorithms, 2nd edition": Implementation of the deletion algorithm in C++ looks like this:

```
template<class Tree_T, class Node_T>
void rb_delete(Tree_T* t,Node_T* z)
{
    Node_T* y = nullptr;
    Node_T* x = nullptr;
    if (!get_left(z) || !get_right(z))
    {
        y = z;
    }
    else
    {
        //y = rb_successor(z);
        y = rb_predecessor(z);
    }
    if (get_left(y))
    {
        x = get_left(y);
    }
    else
    {
        x = get_right(y);
    }
    set_parent(x,get_parent(y));
    if (!get_parent(y))
    {
        set_root(t,x);
    }
    else
    {
        if (y == get_left(get_parent(y)))
        {
            set_left(get_parent(y),x);
        }
        else
        {
            set_right(get_parent(y),x);
        }
    }
    if (y != z)
    {
        set_key(z,get_key(y));
        set_value(z,get_value(y));
    }
    if(get_color>(y) == Black)
    {
        rb_delete_fixup(t,x);
    }
}

template<class Tree_T, class Node_T>
void rb_delete_fixup(Tree_T* t, Node_T* x)
{
    while (x != get_root(t) && get_color(x) == Black)
    {
        //more code here but it never gets executed!
    }
    set_color(x,Black);
}
```

The problem is that when I create tree in order 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 
the tree looks like this:

[image]

If I were to delete root from this tree I'm getting:

```
void rb_delete(Tree_T* t,Node_T* z)//t is the tree, z is a node with key 4
    {
        Node_T* y = nullptr;
        Node_T* x = nullptr;
        if (!get_left(z) || !get_right(z))//z has left && right so this will get skipped
        {
            y = z;
        }
        else
        {
            //y = rb_successor(z);
            y = rb_predecessor(z);//to here where y will be set to 3
        }
if (get_left(y))//this is false
        {
            x = get_left(y);
        }
        else//so we skipping to this place
        {
            x = get_right(y);//and here x goes set to nullptr!
        }
        set_parent(x,get_parent(y));//cannot set, x == nullptr
        if (!get_parent(y))//this is false
        {
            set_root(t,x);
        }
        else
        {
            if (y == get_left(get_parent(y)))//this is false
            {
                set_left(get_parent(y),x);
            }
            else
            {
                set_right(get_parent(y),x);//so here we set right of parent y to nullptr
            }
        }
        if (y != z)//this is true
        {
            set_key(z,get_key(y));
            set_value(z,get_value(y));
        }
        if(get_color>(y) == Black)//this is true aswell
        {
            rb_delete_fixup(t,x);//here we attempting to do fixup but x == nullptr!
        }
    }
//So we are going into rb_delete_fixup
     template<class Tree_T, class Node_T>
        void rb_delete_fixup(Tree_T* t, Node_T* x)//x == nullptr
        {
            while (x != get_root(t) && get_color(x) == Black)//this will get skipped because x == nullptr so no code will be executed within while loop!
            {
                //more code here but it never gets executed!
            }
            set_color(x,Black);//here x which is nullptr will get colored to Black
        }
```

This code obviously doesn't work, bear in mind it is implemented line by line from book mentioned at the beginning of this question.

Could anyone help me and explain to me how shall I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it to see where its behaviour diverges from what you expect?

Comment: @Oli yes, I've tried and I 'think' that the fact that x is set to nullptr isn't the way it should be, yet I cannot see other possibility really.

Comment: In `rb_delete` you're using `y = rb_predecessor(z)` rather than the commented out `y = rb_successor(z)` (I'm 99% sure, having implemented a rb tree from the same book, that this is wrong).

Comment: @user786653 it doesn't matter if predecessor instead of successor will be used. That's why it is commented out to try two options. They in this book also say that this isn't important. So all your 99% are wrong.

Comment: Eh sorry, was just comparing your code to mine looking for differences. The way I got mine working was to actually use sentinel nodes (that is a dummy node attached to each rbtree called `nil`) rather than having it represented by `nullptr`. I think if you're going that route you need to pass extra information around as IIRC (hey I might be 99% wrong again) the sentinel is used to store e.g. the parent of y (section 13.4 in the book).

Comment: @user786653 yes, I agree that the dummy sentinels may be the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Another agreement then. If you have a sentinel, x will not be set to null, but point at the sentinel.

Comment: @user336359: The tar file found [here](http://www.mit.edu/~emin/source_code/cpp_trees/index.html) has an implementation you might find useful as a reference. In particular it helped me realize I shouldn't mutate the sentinel (nil) node in my rotate function.

Comment: I eventually did it but it does surprise me that no one (it seems like that to me anyway) never contacted authors of this book and let them know that it IS IMPOSSIBLE TO IMPLEMENT this code line by line using just plain pointers as only those are mentioned in this book. Yes this code works fine when the tree is already build to some extent but IT DOESN'T WORK when we want to build this tree from scratch. It just doesn't. Not if it is implemented using pointers and going line by line what's in this book.